# WORDPRESS: Insert SWF in home page instead of post

Tags: php, wordpress, actionscript-3, flash, wordpress-theming

I have wordpress flash game website. Into the admin panel, where I add or edit post I have field named Swf URL: where I add SWF link and it links to the post where it shows flash game. I want to do same but not in the post, I want to use this function (adding game with the help of swf) to home page.

How it is now:

[image]

How I want to see:

[image]

**functions code:**

```
load_theme_textdomain( "freebabyhazelgames", TEMPLATEPATH."/languages" );
$locale = get_locale( );
$locale_file = TEMPLATEPATH."/languages/{$locale}.php";
if ( is_readable( $locale_file ) )
{
    require_once( $locale_file );
}
$sp_boxes = array( "Game Details" => array( array( "thumb", "Game image URL:" ), array( "game", "Swf URL:" ) ) );
add_action( "admin_menu", "sp_add_custom_box" );
add_action( "save_post", "sp_save_postdata", 1, 2 );
if ( !function_exists( "get_custom_field" ) )
{
    function get_custom_field( $field )
    {
        global $post;
        $custom_field = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $field, true );
        echo $custom_field;
    }
}
```

**post code:**

```
<div id="playgame">
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        <!--
                        swf("<?php $values = get_post_custom_values("game"); echo $values[0]; ?>", "701", "550");//-->
                        </script>
                    </div>
```

By the way I tried to change dirrectory or to copy single.php to index.php but both not worked.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right, you want the game to appear on the main page without entering a post? In that case, I think you can try using a static frontpage instead of latest posts.

You can find it on Appearance -> Customize, and then choose the frontpage to be static. That way you can have your game on the static frontpage.

Comment: I tried it but its only possible to do it for pages not for posts. I have special field to write swf link only for posts not for pages. but you understand clearly.

Comment: Okey. Try this plugin, http://wordpress.org/plugins/nurelm-get-posts/ 
It lets you pull the latest posts to a page by using shortcodes. 

     [get_posts numberposts=1 orderby="date"]

Comment: @user3771854, follow Ahmed advice and just make the swf field appear inside pages. Customize the function `sp_add_custom_box` in your code.